# Still bug in Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

The output of the command in version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
Reduce[Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]] ==  0 && x >= 0 && x <= 4*Pi, x, Reals]
```

> `x == 4*Pi + 4*ArcTan[Root[1 - 8*#1 + 2*#1^2 + 8*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 2, 0]] ||  x == 4*ArcTan[Root[1 - 8*#1 + 2*#1^2 + 8*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 3, 0]] ||  x == 4*ArcTan[Root[1 - 8*#1 + 2*#1^2 + 8*#1^3 + #1^4 & , 4, 0]]`

is incomplete as

```
NSolve[Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]] ==  0 && x >= 0 && x <= 4*Pi, x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> 0.523599}, {x -> 2.61799}, {x -> 4.71239}, {x ->  6.80678}, {x -> 8.90118}, {x -> 10.9956}}`

shows. That bug was submitted by me in January, 2018.

Is there a workaround (`RootApproximant` is not taken into consideration.)?

PS. As I understand it now, we see bugs in

```
NSolve[Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]] ==  0 && x >= 0 && x <= 4*Pi, x, Reals]
```

and in

```
Plot[Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]], {x, 0, 4*Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

, but not a bug in

```
Reduce[Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]] ==  0 && x >= 0 && x <= 4*Pi, x, Reals]
```

Both `NSolve` and `Plot` do not take into account the domains `Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]>0` and `Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]>0`. It became clear if we draw separately

```
Plot[{Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]], Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]]}, {x,  0, 4*Pi}]
```

[image]
Both plots are defined only from `0` to `Pi` and from `3*Pi-Pi/2` to `3*Pi` and from `4*Pi-Pi/2`
to `4*Pi`.

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2022.2 `Student:-Calculus1:-Roots (log[2] (cos (2*x) + cos (x/2)) + 
     log[1/2] (sin (x) + cos (x/2)) = 0, x = 0 .. 4*Pi)` correctly returns `[Pi/6, (5*Pi)/6, (3*Pi)/2, (13*Pi)/6, (17*Pi)/6, (7*Pi)/2]`.

Comment: why not remove the inequalities then use `equation // Solve // FullSimplify` then add the 2Pi*k then maybe `Reduce`

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Unfortunately, `Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]] == 0 // 
  Solve // FullSimplify` performs `{{x -> -(\[Pi]/2)}, {x -> (3 \[Pi])/2}, {x -> -((7 \[Pi])/6)}, {x -> (
   5 \[Pi])/6}, {x -> -((11 \[Pi])/6)}, {x -> \[Pi]/6}}`, where `x->-Pi/2` is simply wrong and "Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information". Thank you anyway for your directions.

Comment: What is wrong in my question?

Comment: That is why I said you should add the 2*Pi*k

Comment: Solve might be doing the same as in my answer but it also inverses the Tan without adding the constants

Comment: @user64494: I am not familiar with Maple and do not know how it treats multiple roots but its output is not 100% correct too. There are in fact 8 roots in the interval `0<=x<=4π` - four simple roots and two double roots. So if there was not a bug Mathematica would output list of eight roots.

Comment: @azerbajdzan; You are right. However,  I don't find any multiplicity notion/option in the documentation to `Reduce`.

Comment: @userrandrand: You wrote "then add the 2Pi*k" . Sorry ,but the function under consideration has its smallest positive  period `4*Pi` as `FunctionPeriod[  Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]], x]` results in.

Comment: Yeah I realized after. I was being loose with what I was saying I just wanted to say that you could add the multiplicity of solutions by hand. I did not know about `FunctionPeriod` thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]];

FunctionPeriod[expr, x]

(* 4 π *)

eqn1 = expr == 0 // Simplify

(* Log[Cos[x/2] + Cos[2 x]] == Log[Cos[x/2] + Sin[x]] *)
```

Similarly to solution by azerbajdzan

```
eqn2 = ApplySides[Exp, eqn1] // Simplify

(* Cos[2 x] == Sin[x] *)

sol = {Reduce[eqn2 && 0 <= x <= 4 Pi, x, Reals] // ToRules}

(* {{x -> π/6}, {x -> (5 π)/6}, {x -> (3 π)/2}, {x -> (13 π)/6}, 
   {x -> (17 π)/6}, {x -> (7 π)/2}}
```

Checking this solution against the original expression,

```
expr == 0 /. sol

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Numerically,

```
solN = NSolve[expr == 0 && 0 <= x <= 4 Pi, x, Reals,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {{x -> 0.52359877559829887308}, {x -> 2.6179938779914943654}, {x -> 
   4.7123889803846898577}, {x -> 6.8067840827778853500}, {x -> 
   8.9011791851710808423}, {x -> 10.995574287564276335}} *)

solN2 = solN /. z_?NumericQ :> RootApproximant[z/Pi]*Pi

(* {{x -> π/6}, {x -> (5 π)/6}, {x -> (3 π)/2}, {x -> (13 π)/6}, 
   {x -> (17 π)/6}, {x -> (7 π)/2}} *)
```

or

```
solN3 = solN /. z_?NumericQ :> Rationalize[z/Pi, 0]*Pi

(* {{x -> π/6}, {x -> (5 π)/6}, {x -> (3 π)/2}, {x -> (13 π)/6}, 
   {x -> (17 π)/6}, {x -> (7 π)/2}}
```

These are identical to the solution provided by `Reduce`

```
solN2 === solN3 === sol

(* True *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[expr, {x, 0, 4 Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red,
   AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x, 0} /. sol]}]
```

[image]

Generalizing from a sequence,

```
seq = x /. sol

(* {π/6, (5 π)/6, (3 π)/2, (13 π)/6, (17 π)/6, (7 π)/2} *)

solG = ConditionalExpression[
  FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // Simplify, Element[n, Integers]]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], expr == 0 /. x -> solG // 
  FullSimplify]

(* True )
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the `Log` is redundant in this case we can get rid of it and solve simplified equation, which give correct result

```
Log[2, Cos[2 x] + Cos[x/2]] + Log[1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[x/2]] == 
  0 // FullSimplify
Solve[% /. Log -> Identity, x, Reals]
Solve[%% \[And] 0 <= x <= 4 π /. Log -> Identity, x, Reals]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your work. Unfortunately, your claim "Since the Log is redundant in this case we can get rid of it and solve simplified equation" is not correct: we should take into account the domains `Cos[x/2] + Cos[2 x]>0` and `Cos[x/2] + Cos[2 x]>0` over the reals. Therefore, `Log -> Identity` is built on the sand. Also `Solve` admits non-equivalent transformations, `Reduce` doesn't.

Comment: No, both expressions can be negative, why not? `Log` works fine with negative arguments  and, say, `x=-(π/2)` is a valid solution over reals even though expression inside logarithm is negative. The only issue would be if both expression under `Log` are `0` but that does not happen for our equation and even if it happen it would still be a valid solution as a limit case.

Comment: +1, however, for your work and good intentions.

Comment: You wrote " both expressions can be negative, why not?". This contradicts usual conventions in equation solving and Mathematica keeps those.

Comment: Compare `Solve[Log[x^2 - 1] == Log[x - 1] - 1, x, Reals]` which results in `{}` and `Solve[Log[x^2 - 1] == Log[x - 1] - 1, x]` which performs `x == (1 - E)/E`.

Comment: Do you realize that for `x=(3 π)/2` the expression under your original logarithms are negative too? How is it that you accept this particular solution but not mine that fulfills exactly the same conditions?

Comment: mistake... I meant `3/2` not `5/6`

Comment: You are right. This is a bug and a false solution over the reals..